# Rails: undefined method `joins' for Searchable?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, searchable

I used: `include Searchable` for `model/post.rb`.

In post.rb, i have:
`Worker.joins(...)`.

The error I'm getting: `undefined method 'joins' for Searchable::Worker:Module`.
If i delete `include Searchable`, it run.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a namespace issue. Explicitly require top-level Worker

```
 ::Worker.joins(...)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You save my day.

Comment: @AvadaKedavra: Don't forget to accept the answer :)